# How can I route to a specific quiz based on quizId?

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routerlink

I'm working on a quiz-selection component. I would like it to route to specific quiz based on quiz.id in QUIZ_DATA array in external quiz.ts file, for example TS-Quiz or DI-Quiz. When I click on the TypeScript Quiz (TS-Quiz), I am getting the DI-Quiz intro; it should be the TS-Quiz intro information. Not sure how to use the quiz.id type that is passed to the IntroductionComponent in [routerLink].

And I'm getting this error when loading the first question in the quiz:
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

I would like it so that the select page is first (done), followed by intro (based on quiz.id), then questions (based on quiz.id), then results.

Please see my running app on Stackblitz: **https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-quiz-app**

My [routerLink] is below:

```html
<mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let quiz of quizData"
  [routerLink]="['/quiz/intro', quiz.id]"
  [ngStyle]="{ 'background': 'url(' + quiz.imageUrl + ') no-repeat center top',
               'background-size': '380px 275px' }">
```

My IntroductionComponent looks like:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let quiz of quizData">
  <mat-card *ngIf="quiz.id === 'DI_Quiz'">
    <mat-card-header>
      <div mat-card-avatar class="header-image"></div>
      <mat-card-title i18n>{{ quiz.milestone }} Quiz</mat-card-title>
      <mat-card-subtitle i18n>
        <span>How well do you know {{ quiz.milestone }}?</span>
        <span>Take the quiz and find out!</span>
      </mat-card-subtitle>
    </mat-card-header>
...
<mat-card-actions>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" routerLink="/quiz/question/1">
     <span i18n><strong>Start the Quiz!</strong></span>
  </button>
</mat-card-actions>
```

And here's my routing setup in my quiz-routing.module.ts:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'select' },
  { path: 'select', component: QuizSelectionComponent },
  { path: 'intro', component: IntroductionComponent },
  { path: 'intro/:id', component: IntroductionComponent },
  { path: 'question', component: QuizComponent },
  { path: 'question/:questionIndex', component: QuizComponent },
  { path: 'results', component: ResultsComponent }
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the `quiz.component.ts`, in `getQuestion (line 85)` method, the `getQuestions` method of the Quiz Service returns an array, not a object. So, the property questions will be undefined.

Looks like the quiz id is missing, you need to get the quiz id to get the questions of that quiz, something like this:

```js
this.question = this.quizService.getQuestions()[indexOfQuizId].questions[this.questionIndex - 1];
```

To get the `indexOfQuizId`, one approach is change the route of question page to:

```js
{ path: 'question/:quizId/:questionIndex', component: QuizComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
```

and then get the index of the quiz with something like that:

```js
const quizId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('quizId');
const indexOfQuizId = this.quizData.findIndex(el => el.id === quizId);
```

Ofcourse are others ways to do that, this is only one method.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'm having trouble getting the index of quiz id, trying this: const indexOfQuizId = this.quizData.findIndex((element ) => element.id === this.quizName); 
 console.log(indexOfQuizId) gives -1

Comment: I'm still having this issue. Need this to get the quiz questions to display. Please could you help. Thank you.

Comment: You can change your route to get the quiz name and then get the index, I will improve my answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks. I added the code to my Stackblitz and updated the routerLink in the "Start the Quiz" button in IntroductionComponent to [routerLink]="['/question/', quiz.id, 1]" and when I click the button in my IntroductionComponent, nothing happens, no message in console and nothing is displayed.

Comment: I updated quizData: Quiz[] and the quizData usages and this.question in the QuizService for multiple quizzes.

Comment: getQuestions() and numberOfQuestions() in the QuizService seem to be the problem, I'm getting this error: "Cannot read property 'questions' of undefined"

Comment: I'm still getting this error, nothing is displayed.

Comment: I saw that you are trying to get the questionnaire parameters directly from the service, It's better to do this in your component and pass the parameters to the service to avoid problems like you have now.

Comment: I think you need to review the flow of your application and be aware of the separation of responsibilities. There are several things you need to address and it starts to fall outside the scope of this issue.

Comment: I've refactored the code to get the params in the QuizComponent and will try to pass the totalQuestions to the QuizService and also to the ScoreComponent and ScoreboardComponent.

Comment: Thanks, the quiz question routing is now working! The mat-accordion doesn't expand in the ResultsComponent (*ngFor has unresolved variable questions).  Also I just noticed in my quiz the correctMessage remains the same in the DI Quiz for all the questions when the quiz starts with multiple choice question.

Comment: I passed the questions to ResultsComponent and mat-accordion works now, trying to set and pass the Resources similarly...

Comment: The correctMessage seems to display fine for all questions on Stackblitz, but doesn't seem to display correctly locally in IntelliJ...

Comment: correctMessage variable was initialized in ngOnInit and setSelected, removed it from ngOnInit and it works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

The routing parameter can be obtained as follows,

Update your `introduction.component.ts` like below,

```js
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component } from '@angular/core';

import { QUIZ_DATA } from '../../shared/quiz';
import { Quiz } from '../../shared/models/Quiz.model';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'codelab-quiz-intro',
  templateUrl: './introduction.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./introduction.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class IntroductionComponent {
  quizData: Quiz = QUIZ_DATA;
  quizName: String = '';

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {}

 ngOnInit() {
    this.route.url.subscribe(segments => {
          this.quizName = segments[1].toString();
    });
 }

}
```

Update the `mat-card *ngIf` in `introduction.component.html` like below,

```html
<mat-card *ngIf="quiz.id === quizName">
```

This will help in correctly navigating to the required intro page based on the chosen quiz. Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-quiz-app-ndn8wz)